# Can't figure out what is breaking my responsive website

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I recently updated plugins on my website and I can't figure out what broke the responsive design. Seems like it may be the photo but I have tried that. Does anyone have a potential fix? Would be very grateful.

https://markfulton.com/

Yes, I understand the irony of me being a website developer, but sometimes the wisdom of the crowd is very helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `display: flex;` to the `section .container` class styles fixes the section container content expanding past the width of the screen issue on the tablet-sized screen.

Removing this should solve the grey space above the header on smaller screens:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 650px)
  #wrapper {
    /* top: 200px !important;
  }
```